# Getting Retina Screen Resolution on Macs with HiDPI in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-resolution, retina-display, unity-editor, hidpi

I am making a custom Unity Editor GUI window and I just want it to stay and the exact center of the screen. Surprisingly, this is harder than I thought it would be on Macs.

This is my code:

```
....
windowRect.center = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.currentResolution.width, Screen.currentResolution.height).center;
....
```

The problem is, on a 5K iMac, which has a native resolution of 5120*2880, by default the macOS uses HiDPI to scale everything to 2560*1440. In Unity, **Screen.currentResolution** returns 5120*2880 without considering HiDPI scaling, but I need that sweet scaled resolution.

I've tried other functions as well. **Display.main.systemWidth** returns 1920 instead of 5120 or 2560.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I just out of luck? I am using Unity 2018.1.9f1.

Also, if there is a way to get the size of the whole Unity Editor Window(not the game window), I would be fine with it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This in an old thread, but in case someone is still wondering, I found out that the highest resolution returned by Screen.resolutions on a retina device is the « magic » resolution. It’s the one that you see in the device settings as « Looks like X x Y ».

This is not mentioned in the doc as far as I could see, so I am not certain in can be relied upon in the long run, but it’s the case currently with Unity 2018.3.

Answer (score 0):

In **Editor**, **Screen.currentResolution** show the resolution of game window. You can enable **Maximize On Play** to use the maximized window resolution.

And if you deploy to MacOS app, it should be the 5K resolution correctly.

Comment: At least for me, in **editor**, **Screen.currentResolution** still returns the resolution of the screen "physical pixel dimensions", **not** the resolution of the game window. Besides, what I need is the HiDPI simulated screen resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same as centre of the screen, but I was having a similar issue and solved it using:

```
EditorGUIUtility.GetMainWindowPosition().center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. You may be looking for any of the following

```
EditorGUIUtility.pixelsPerPoint
EditorGUIUtility.PointsToPixels
EditorGUIUtility.PixelsToPoints
```